# Neo4j pure Cypher alternative for apoc.coll.intersection

Tags: neo4j, cypher, apoc

In order to find an intersection of two arrays, I use the following APOC call:

```
apoc.coll.intersection($detailedCriterionIds, childD.detailedCriterionIds)
```

Could you please show how to implement the same with pure Cypher without APOC help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
[x IN list1 WHERE x IN list2 | x]
```

In this example, you iterate over all elements in `list1` and only keep those elements that are also in `list2`